# How to reverse all the strings inside an array in an elasticsearch document with a groovy script?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have an elasticsearch document

`{
   "_index": "testindex",
   "_type": "testtype",
   "_id": "doc1",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "array": [
         "abc",
         "def",
         "ghi"
      ]
   }
}`

How do I reverse all the strings inside the array in the document? I tried using update api with the following script

`temp = []; for(String item : ctx._source.array) temp << item.reverse(); ctx._source.array = temp;`

Update api in java :

```
new org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest(index, type, docId).script(script);
```

I am getting an exception like method call not allowed inside the script.

```
Bulk request failure, id: [doc4], message: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: GroovyScriptCompilationException[MultipleCompilationErrorsException[startup failed:
General error during canonicalization: Method calls not allowed on [java.lang.String]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: click too see the pic]try this

```
temp=[];

ctx._source.array.each{

    it -> temp.add(it.reverse())
}

ctx._source.array = temp
```

Comment: The exception is thrown because of the usage of reverse() function in the groovy script.

Comment: I agree that it is a valid groovy script. But when I gave the same script along with elasticsearch update api, I got the above mentioned exception.

Comment: then the value coming inside  clouser is not a string , then convert that as toString()    and try reverse on that. Hope this helps